# Link to previous/next record by specific attribute type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Animal model which at the moment consists of Cats and Dog. I have a column called animal_type that will define what the animal is

When I view a record (show action) then it could be any animal type and I have created next and previous links to cycle through all the animal records:

```
def next_animal
 animal = self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at > ?', self.created_at)
 animal.first if animal
end

def previous_animal
 animal = self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at < ?', self.created_at)
 animal.last if animal
end
```

Controller

```
def show
 @animal = Animal.find(params[:id])
end
```

View

```
<% if @animal.previous_animal %>
  <%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal, {class: 'prev-page'}) do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= @animal.previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(@animal.previous_animal) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So if I am looking at a dog, what do I need to do to say only be able to cycle through the next and previous dogs, and not include any cat, and vice versa, so if I'm looking at a cat record, only cycle through other cats.

I've thought about a scope

```
scope :dog_type, -> { where(animal_type: 'Dog') }
```

but still unsure on how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# model
def previous_animal
  self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at < ?', self.created_at).where(animal_type: self.animal_type).first
end

# view
<% if previous_animal = @animal.previous_animal %> # local assignment in the if condition
  <%= link_to(previous_animal, {class: 'prev-page'}) do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Meet <span class="name"><%= previous_animal.name %></span>, the <%= animal_breed(previous_animal) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

- The `previous_animal` method is simplified, calling `.first` on an ActiveRecord::Relation can't fail, but it can return `nil`.
- I used the local variable assignment in the if condition because every time you call `previous_animal` on the record it trigger a SQL query. This local variable kind of act like a cache (won't trigger the SQL query multiple times).

Comment: thanks MrYoshiji, any difference in performance between the two answers ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I just updated my answer with the arguments.

Comment: thank you thats a great explanation... so the more i can assign to local variables the better the performance ?

Comment: No it does not work like that, you have to "know" what is done by your methods. Here the method is triggering a SQL query to retrieve a record following some conditions. If you call it twice, it will trigger the SQL query twice, which is unnecessary since you already found it like 5 ms before. In this case, you "cache" the record found in a local variable, and use it directly to use this record. It is behaving like a shortcut if you prefer, but it is not a shortcut. I don't know if I'm clear, probably not. Other people are welcome to give input here!

Comment: Ah that does make more sense, I'll do some more reading on the matter though , thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def next_animal
 animal = self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at > ? and animal_type = ?', created_at, animal_type)
 animal.first if animal
end
```

Just add it in the where, if you use scopes then you're going to need an if statement in your previous and next.

Comment: would you be able to expand the answer a little please?

Comment: ah dont worry, i see what you mean now, if i was to use scopes then i would have to use an if statement, adding it in the where gets rid of the need to use scopes, thank you